# Variable scope in java script and ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

this is my code:

```
var PID = (this.settings.id);
var MySeatString = 'null';

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'http://localhost:14481/Fa/DBStuff.aspx?PID=' + PID;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var arr = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var i;
    var out = '';
    if (arr[0].Situ == 'ok') {
      MySeatString = arr[0].Seat;
    } else {
      alert('error: ' + arr[0].Situ);
    }
  }
}

xmlhttp.open('POST', url, true);
xmlhttp.send();
alert(MySeatString);
```

the problem is `MySeatString = null` in the end of the code. But `arr[0].Seat = available`
how can i access `arr[0].Seat` after  `xmlhttp.send();`
I'm new to java script.
thank you.

Comment: Any reason why we have to scroll to the right to actually see your code?

Comment: @LeonelAtencio That is not correct advice with an asynchronous call.

Comment: Yeah!. I realized that seconds after i commented. Was just answering based on the question, not the actual code.